# Why is a change of orthonormal bases orthogonal?

Tags: matrices, orthogonality, orthonormal

Suppose that $\mathcal{U}$ is a k-dimensional subspace in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and we have two sets of orthonormal basis vectors for it, collected into the columns of a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$ and a matrix $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$. It is easy to show that there exists a matrix $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$ such that $A=BQ$. I would like to show that $Q$ is orthogonal -- that is, I want to show that $Q^TQ=QQ^T=I_k$. To show that $Q^TQ=I$ is easy: from $A=BQ$, we have $B^TA = Q$, since $B$ has orthonormal columns. Then, 
\begin{equation}
Q^TQ = A^TBQ = A^TA = I_k,
\end{equation}
since the columns of $A$ are orthonormal.

I am having trouble showing that $QQ^T=I_k$ also. Namely, 
\begin{equation}
QQ^T = B^TAA^TB,
\end{equation}
and I'm having trouble showing that $AA^TB=B$. Some other answers on stack exchange indicate that if a matrix has orthonormal columns, then its rows are automatically also orthonormal. I am not sure why that is the case.

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: $QQ^t = I$ then $Q^{-1} = Q^t$

Comment: @uniquesolution in this case it trivially is because they're symmetric and equal, but in general the two matrices are symmetric and not equal, and in particular neither is the transpose of the other.

Comment: @uniquesolution you missed the point. The matrix IS symmetric, and $AA^T$ is NOT the transpose of $A^TA$. Transposing reverses the order of products; $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$. $(AA^T)^T=(A^T)^TA^T=AA^T\neq A^TA$.

Comment: Yes, you are right.